# In what condition we should use `[ ] a` in a type declaration?

Tags: haskell, type-declaration

I just see an expression

```
fmap_List :: (a -> b) -> [] a -> [] b
-- "[] a" means "[a]", for types.
fmap_List f [] = []
fmap_List f (x:xs) = f x : fmap_List f xs
```

Since `[] a` means `[a]`, why we don't put `[a]` directly instead? Are there some special cases we should use `[] a`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It’s just avoiding the syntactic sugar `[a]` as a way of illustrating that the `f` type parameter of `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` is being replaced with the type constructor `[]`, just like any other type constructor.

That is, you might write the type `[a]` as `[] a` when you want to emphasise the relationship to a signature that’s polymorphic over some type constructor, like `fmap`:

```
fmap       :: Functor f => (a -> b) ->     f a ->     f b

-- f = []
fmap_List  ::              (a -> b) ->    [] a ->    [] b
fmap_List = fmap

-- f = Maybe
fmap_Maybe ::              (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
fmap_Maybe = fmap
```

Or `join`:

```
join      :: Monad m =>  m ( m a) ->  m a
join_List ::            [] ([] a) -> [] a
```

This is exactly the same as `[[a]] -> [a]`, just making it clearer that `m` = `[]`.

`[] a` is the type constructor `[]` applied to the type variable `a`. `[] a` or `[a]` has the kind `*`, the kind of types that are inhabited by values, such as `Int`, `Char`, `Maybe Int`, or `Either String Int`. `[]` has kind `* -> *`, the kind of types that take a type argument and produce a type as a result, such as `[]`, `Maybe`, `Identity`, or `Either e`.

You can see this for example in the definition of `instance Monad []`—we’re giving the *constructor* `[]` (of kind `* -> *`) as an argument to `Monad` (of kind `(* -> *) -> Constraint`), not a *type* (of kind `*`) made with that constructor such as `instance Monad ([] a)`. This is just like using `Maybe` instead of `Maybe a`, `Maybe Int`, `Maybe String`, &c.

Using the `TypeApplications` pragma, you can explicitly apply polymorphic functions to type arguments, e.g. in GHCi:

```
> :set -XTypeApplications

> :type fmap @[]
fmap @[] :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]

> :type fmap @Maybe
fmap @Maybe :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b

> :type fmap @[] @Int @Char
fmap @[] @Int @Char :: (Int -> Char) -> [Int] -> [Char]

> :type fmap @[] @_ @Bool
fmap @[] @_ @Bool :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [Bool]
```

This is very useful for figuring out how to use polymorphic functions, or documenting which container or monad you’re using such a function with, by specialising a type to a (more) concrete instance:

```
> :type traverse
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)

> :type traverse @[] @IO
traverse @[] @IO :: (a -> IO b) -> [a] -> IO [b]
```

And you can also ask GHCi for the kind of a type to get a better understanding of kinds:

```
> :kind Either
Either :: * -> * -> *

> :kind Either String
Either String :: * -> *

> :kind Either String Int
Either String Int :: *

> :kind []
[] :: * -> *

> :kind [] Int
[] Int :: *

> :kind [Int]
[Int] :: *

> :kind Functor
Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint

> :kind Num
Num :: * -> Constraint
```

Comment: I can also imagine it being helpful to illustrate a natural transformation: `listToMaybe :: [] a -> Maybe a`

Answer (score 4):

The notation `[]` is useful when it is not being applied but passed to another type constructor.

```
Fix []              -- recursion-schemes
Free [] a           -- free
ReaderT r [] a      -- transformers
Compose [] Maybe a  -- base (Data.Functor.Compose)
```

Comment: Do you mean, for example, the input is a list and the output is still a list? I don't quite understand what "not being applied" means.

Comment: `[] a` is the *type constructor* `[]` applied to a type `a`, which is more commonly written `[a]`, and in practice there is no reason to write `[] a` instead. But the type constructor can also be used by itself, and I gave some examples of types where that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

> Since `[] a` means `[a]`, why we don't put `[a]` directly instead?

This is a funny question. Let me try to convince you that, arguably, the real question is:

> Since `[a]` means `[] a`, why we don't put `[] a` directly instead?

Consider the following parametric types:

```
data Identity a = Identity a
data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
data HPair a = HPair a a
data HTriple a = HTriple a a a
data Tree a = Empty | Branch (Tree a) a (Tree a)
data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)
data [a] = [] | (a : [a])
```

Note that *all* of these have the form `TypeConstructor a`, except for `[a]`! Indeed, to make the world more coherent, we should actually write `[] a` instead of `[a]`.

This also makes it clear that `[]` is a type constructor, exactly like `Identity, Maybe, Tree, ...`.

The syntax `[a]` is convenient, and possibly easier to read, especially for a beginner. However, it makes understanding the real nature of `[]` harder. `Maybe` has no such issue, by comparison.